# Zend Framework 3 Error al entrar a una vista: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, zend

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Zend Framework 3, quiero visualizar un formulario que hice con zend form, pero a la hora de cargar la página me marca el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo ni idea de que pueda ser adjunto los código que uso

create.phtml:

```
<?php
$this->form->prepare();
$this->form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('actividad', ['action' => 'resultado']))
        ->setAttribute('method', 'post')
        ->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal')
        ->setAttribute('role', 'form');
?>

<style>
    .uper{
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
</style>
<div class="card.uper">
    <div class="card-header">
        Agregar Actividad
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">


            <div class="form-group">
                <!-- <label for="description">Actividad</label>-->
                <?= $this->form()->formLabel($this->form->get('descripcion'))?>
                <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion"/> -->
                <?= $this->form()->formInput($this->form->get('descripcion'))?>
                <div style="color: red"><?= $this->formElementErrors($this->form->get('descripcion'))?></div>
            </div>

            <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button> -->
            <?= $this->formSubmit($this->form->get('guardar'))?>
        </form>
    </div><br/>
</div>
```

El controlador ActividadController.php:

```
    <?php

namespace Frank\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Form\Actividad as ActividadForm;
use Zend\Form\ActividadValidator;

class ActividadController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function indexAction() {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function editAction() {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function createAction() {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function formAction() {
        $form = new Actividad("actividad");
        return ['form' => $form, 'titulo' => 'Formularios con ZF3'];
    }

    public function resultadoAction() {
        //$this->redirect()->toRoute('actividad', ['action' => 'create']);
        // Obtenemos los parámetros del formulario es similar a $_POST
        $postParams = $this->request->getPost();

        $form = $this->getForm();
        $form->setInputFilter(new ActividadValidator());

        $form->setData($postParams);

        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            // Falla la validación; volvemos a generar el formulario 
            $modelView = new ViewModel(['form' => $form, 'titulo' => "Validando campos del estudiante"]);
            $modelView->setTemplate('frank/actividad/create');
            return $modelView;
        }

        $values = $form->getData();

        //$estudiante = new Estudiante();
        //$estudiante->exchangeArray($values);

        return new ViewModel(['titulo' => "Detalle del Estudiante", 'estudiante' => $estudiante]);

    }

}
```

Este el el formulario Actividad.php:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Frank\Form;

use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class Actividad extends Form {

    public function __construct($name = null) {
        parent::__construct($name);

        $this->add([
            'type' => Element\Text::class,
            'name' => 'descripcion',
            'attributes' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label1' => 'Descripcion',
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'guardar',
            'type' => Element\Submit::class,
            'attributes' => [
                'value' => 'Guardar',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
            ],
        ]);
    }

}
?>
```

el validator ActividadValidator.php:

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Validator\StringLength;
use Zend\Validator\Identical;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Input;
use Zend\I18n\Validator\Alnum;
use Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator as TranslatorMvc;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

/**
 * Description of EstudianteValidator
 *
 * @author Andres
 */
class EstudianteValidator extends InputFilter {

    protected $opcionesStringLength = [
        'min' => 4,
        'max' => 50,
        'messages' => [
            StringLength::TOO_SHORT => "El campo debe tener tener al menos 4 caracteres",
            StringLength::TOO_LONG => "El campo debe tener un máximo de 50 caracteres",
        ]
    ];
    protected $opcionesAlnum = [
        //con esto acepta espacios en blanco
        'allowWhiteSpace' => true,
        'messages' => [
            'notAlnum' => "El valor  no es alfanúmerico",
        ]
    ];

    public function __construct() {

        $translator = new TranslatorMvc(new Translator());
        $translator->addTranslationFile('phparray', './module/Application/language/es_ES.php');
        AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'codigo',
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => Validator\CodigoValidador::class,
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        //validación del set descripcion
        $descripcion = new Input('descripcion');
        //con esto obliga al usuario a que se llene este campo
        $descripcion->setRequired(true);
        $descripcion->getFilterChain()
                //quita etiquetas html y javascript
                ->attachByName('StripTags')
                //quita espacios en blanco
                ->attachByName('StringTrim');

        //agregamos validadores
        $descripcion->getValidatorChain()
                //
                ->addValidator(new StringLength($this->opcionesStringLength))
                //validador alfanumerico
                ->addValidator(new Alnum($this->opcionesAlnum));


    }

}
?>
```

Por el momento, lo único que quiero es que me muestre en pantalla mi vista del formulario, que solamente tiene una caja de texto, una etiqueta y un botón; pero cuando quiero cargar la vista me marca error.

Comment: Estás usando `$this` fuera de una clase; probablemente funcione si incluyes `create.phtml` dentro de uno de los métodos, pero, en todo caso, usa solo `$form`, porque no está definida como propiedad de la clase.

Comment: @Triby el uso de `$this` en las vistas de _Zend_ es correcto, se puede usar tanto `$form` como `$this->form` obteniendo el mismo resultado. El error básicamente es que el _createAction_ (que es de quien depende la vista _create.phtml_) no está enviando el `$form` hacia la vista. Al no recibir el objeto lanza el error.